# How to change the text 'More' on the standard UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a TabBarController with several UITabBarItems, the last of those items is the standard 'More'  UITabBarItem provided by iOS. I want the title to be 'Meer' (More in my language), but when I try to set the title programmatically it doesn't work. I've tried this:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *chauffeurItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *voertuigItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *moreItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

chauffeurItem.title = @"Chauffeurs";
voertuigItem.title = @"Voertuigen";
moreItem.title = @"Meer";
```

This is in my TabBarController. The first two items do change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Info.plist file, and change the "Localization native development region" key to your language. The "more" button title changes automatically. This also auto-changes some other system button titles.

Comment: This works, however, is there no other way to change the text? Or the total appearance for that matter? I want to use the more icon, but with a different selected color.

Answer (score 2):

The `More` button's text should be consistent with your app's language, and your app's language will be set to system's language, *if* it is supported by your app (this is handled by iOS). For example, if the user's system language is Dutch, and your app supports Dutch, `More` should automatically be displayed as `Meer` (again, this is handled by iOS since the button is a system button).

Anyway, you should't be bothering *localizing* the `More` text at this point. If you decide to support multiple languages, you should internationalize then localize your app as a whole. This [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html) will help you through the process.

Comment: Okay, that solves the text issue. But is there a way to modify the tint color of the more icon too?

Comment: Nevermind, I already solved it. Thanks anyway! I am going to accept Rafal's answer since he was the first.